# How to find a all string in ' but exclude lines which contain a System.debug

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I trying to get all data inside ' using this

```
['].*?[']
```

and additionaly i want to exclude lines which is contain System.Debug

i tried

```
^((?!System.debug).)*$['].*?[']
```

but this is not working , what i doing wrong ?

Comment: Maybe something like [`^(?!.*\bSystem.debug\b).*?'(.*?)'`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f!.*%5cbSystem.debug%5cb%29.*%3f%27%28.*%3f%29%27&i=Test+%27test%27%0d%0aSystem.debug+test+%27test%27). But it would depend on how your sample data looks. See the provided link under "table" what is captured in `$1`.

Comment: Also you may consider to escape the dot: `System\.debug`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
(?<!System\.debug.*)'(?!.*System\.debug)[^']*'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vSk4Tk/1) and the Visual Studio Code demo & settings:

[image]

*Details*:

- `(?<!System\.debug.*)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is `System.debug` and any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible immediately to the left of the current location
- `'` - a `'` char
- `(?!.*System\.debug)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then `System.debug` immediately to the right of the current location
- `[^']*` - zero or more chars other than `'`
- `'` - a `'` char.

**NOTE**: In VSCode regex, `[^']` and other negated character classes only match line breaks if there is `\r` or `\n` somewhere in the regex pattern, so it is not necessary to use `[^'\n]`, but it is used in the regex101 demo.